# Contar números y letras de una cadena con javascript

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

De una cadena necesito saber cuántos caracteres hay sin contar espacios o números y mandarlo a imprimir, así como aparte otra función que de esa misma cadena me cuente si hay números y cuantos, igual sin espacios esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora.

Ya me sale cuantos caracteres pero no quiero que me cuente los números, los quiero aparte:

```
function  cadenaNumerosLetras(){
    var frase = document.getElementById(‘cadena’).value;
    var letterCount = frase.split(/\W/).join('').length;
    var contadorLetras = letterCount.toString();
    console.log(letterCount);
    document.getElementById(‘resultado’).value = contadorLetras;
    var numeros = "0123456789";
    if(!isNaN(frase)){
        for(i=0; i<frase.length;i++){
            if(numeros.indexOf(frase.charAt(i),0)!=-1){
                return 1;
                document.getElementById('numeros').innerHTML= frase;
            }
        }
        return 0;          
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Para obtener la longitud de una cadena **sin los espacios**, basta con eliminarlos y obtener la longitud de la cadena resultante:

```js
function lenWithoutSpaces( str ) {
  return str.replace( /\s/g, '' ).length;
}

console.log( lenWithoutSpaces( 'Hola y adiós, mundo cruel !' ) );
```

Para contar los números, te da igual que la cadena tenga o no espacios: un espacio **no es un número**. Puedes usar [`Array.prototype.forEach( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), a través de [`call( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/call), y pasándole la cadena como argumento.

Y, para la comparación, usa [`charCodeAt( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/charCodeAt), que te devuelve el [código ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) del caracter en esa posición.

```js
function countDigits( str ) {
  var acu = 0;

  Array.prototype.forEach.call( str, function( val ) {
    acu += ( val.charCodeAt( 0 ) > 47 ) && ( val.charCodeAt( 0 ) < 58 ) ? 1 : 0;
  } );

  return acu;
}

console.log( countDigits( 'abcde123fgh' ) );
console.log( countDigits( 'abcdefgh' ) );
```

Por último, si lo quieres todo en una sola llamada, puedes devolver un objeto:

```js
function examineString( str ) {
  var acu = 0,
      withoutSpaces = str.replace( /\s/g, '' ).length;

  Array.prototype.forEach.call( str, function( val ) {
    acu += ( val.charCodeAt( 0 ) > 47 ) && ( val.charCodeAt( 0 ) < 58 ) ? 1 : 0;
  } );

  return {
    withoutSpaces: withoutSpaces,
    digitsCount: acu,
    otherChars: withoutSpaces - acu
  };
}

console.log( examineString( 'Pues vaya, después de 10 o 15 intentos, lo encontré :-)' ) );
```

#### EDITO

Para contar los dígitos, también se puede utilizar [`Array.prototype.reduce( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) ... es incluso mas simple:

```js
function countDigits( str ) {
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call( str, function( acu, val ) {
    return ( val.charCodeAt( 0 ) > 47 ) && ( val.charCodeAt( 0 ) < 58 ) ? acu + 1 : acu;
  }, 0 );
}

console.log( countDigits( 'abcde012fgh' ) );
console.log( countDigits( 'abcdefgh' ) );
```

Comment: muchas gracias :) sos un genio

Comment: Crack en javascript!!!

Comment: @JackNavaRow Pongo en mi CV un enlace a tu comentario :-)

Comment: ya que pa los espacios usas regex, por qué no regex pa los numeros?

Comment: @lois6b ¿ En serio estás comparando la sutil belleza de la programación funcional con una *burrualidad* como son las RegEx ? :-O

Comment: @Trauma las regex **son** *sexies*

Answer (score 6):

Una variación de la respuesta de [@Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/19610/trauma), haciendo el reduce mas [elegante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291445/contar-n%c3%bameros-y-letras-de-una-cadena-con-javascript/291451#comment534714_291451):

1. Creamos constante de los valores que pueden ser posicion 0 es letra mientras que la posicion 1 es numero
2. Usamos la formula de Trauma para buscar aquellos que sean letra y se multiplica por 1(esto es para hacer el cambio a entero)
3. Sumamos el acumulador y listo!

```js
const values = ["letras", "numeros", "espacios"];
function countDigits( str ) {

  return Array.prototype.reduce.call( str, function( acu, val ) {
  
    let pos =  val.charCodeAt( 0 ) == 32 ? 2 : 
             (val.charCodeAt( 0 ) > 47 ) && ( val.charCodeAt( 0 ) < 58) * 1;
    acu[values[pos]]++
    return acu;
  }, {letras : 0, numeros : 0, espacios : 0} );
}

console.log( countDigits( 'abcde012fgh ' ) );
console.log( countDigits( 'abcdefgh' ) );
console.log( countDigits( "asdjn kajsd5 46546 54aaa asdjn kajsd5 46546 " ) );
```

Que viva la Programación Funcional!

Comment: +1 ¡ Sublime ! ¡ La belleza hecha código ! :-O

Comment: si hay espacios no encuentra la posición

Comment: @Emeeus adapte la respuesta para espacios en blanco

Answer (score 5):

Según lo que dices, necesitas:

1. cuántos caracteres hay sin contar espacios o números.
2. mandarlo a imprimir. Los caracteres sin contar espacios o números?
3. si hay números y cuantos, igual sin espacios.

Yo usaría el callback de `replace()`, pasandole 2 expresiones regulares,
`[^\s^\d]` y `\d` respectivamente, de manera de obtener todo junto de una vez lo que necesitas:

```js
const str = "asdjn kajsd5 46546 54aaa";

const c = { noNumeros: "", cantNoNumeros: 0, numeros: "", cantNumeros: 0, }

str.replace(/([^\s^\d])|(\d)/g, (s, p1, p2, ) => {
    if (p1) {
        c.noNumeros += p1;
        c.cantNoNumeros++;
    }
    if (p2) {
        c.numeros += p2;
        c.cantNumeros++;
    }
});

console.log(c);
```

Si lo que quieres es únicamente las cantidades, puedes usar `reduce()` y `test()`:

```js
const str = "asdjn kajsd5 46546 54aaa asdjn kajsd5 46546 ";

const res = [...str].reduce((p,c)=>{
    (/[^\s^\d]/.test(c))?p.cantNoNumeros++:
    (/\d/.test(c))?p.cantNumeros++:null;
    return p;
},{ cantNoNumeros: 0, cantNumeros: 0, });

console.log(res)
```

Comment: el reduce que hicistes se ve muy complejo, creo que lo puedes mejorar, no necesitas hacer dos veces el .test() es lo contrario al otro

Comment: @JackNavaRow Si puede ser, lo que pasa que no es claro "caracteres" , un salto de línea o tab podría no entrar en ninguno grupo por ejémplo.

Answer (score 1):

Considero que el problema también puede resolverse de forma simple con funciones mas comunes como `split()`, `join()` y `filter()`:

```js
function contarNum(cadena) {
    ncad=cadena.split(' ').filter(String).join('').split(''); //convertir la cadena en array de caracteres eliminando los espacios
    nnum=ncad.filter(num => num >= 0 && num <= 9);            //para obtener los numeros solo basta con esta comparacion  
    
    return {
      numeros: nnum.length,                        //total de numeros
      espacios: cadena.split(' ').length-1,        //total de espacios
      otroscaracteres: ncad.length-nnum.length     //el numero de letras es el total de caracteres - el de numeros
    };
  }

//ejemplos

console.log(contarNum('00 6789687 yuhyugi 7tyjk 00'));

console.log(contarNum('asdjn kajsd5 46546 54aaa asdjn kajsd5 46546 '));

console.log(contarNum('abcde123fgh '));

console.log(contarNum('Pues vaya, después de 10 o 15 intentos, lo encontré :-)'));
```

Se pueden comparar los resultados de los ejemplos con los de otras respuestas y se puede observar que son los mismos.

Espero haber contribuido a resolver el problema, saludos.