# Contar la cantidad de caracteres en un string en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, string, algoritmos

Quiero hacer una funcion que dado un string me **cuente la cantidad de apariciones de cada uno de sus caracteres**.. con mi funcion de abajo `contarCaracteresV1()` podia contar un caracter del string pero como hacerlo para cada uno... siguiendo un poco la respuesta de @Orici agregue a mi funcion algunas cosas `contarCaracteresV2()` veo la logica pero me queda un `undefined` del caracter que estaba en mayuscula como puedo corregir esto?? ... El `undefined` era poque los metodos que conosco para quitar caracteres repetidos dejan un arreglo con el elemento `''` cuando quitan un caracter; lo arregle en mi respuesta `contarCaracteresV3()` https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/293573/120346

```js
function contarCaracteresV2(str) {
    let caracteres = [... new Set(str.toLowerCase())]

    for(var i=0; i<caracteres.length; i++){
        let arreglo=[]
        str.split('').map(n => {
            if(n.toLowerCase() === caracteres[i]){
                arreglo.push(n)
            } 
            
        })
        console.log(`La cantidad de ${caracteres[i]} es: ${arreglo.length}`);
    }

}

console.log(contarCaracteresV2("Abcaa"));
```

```js
function contarCaracteresV1(str) {
    let letra = str[0].toLowerCase();
    let arreglo=[]
    str= str.split('');

    str.map(n => {
        if(n.toLowerCase() === letra){
            arreglo.push(n)
        } 
            
    })


    return `La cantidad de ${letra} es: ${arreglo.length}`
}

console.log(contarCaracteresV1("Abcaa"));
```

Comment: Hola, tambien te interesa diferenciar minúscula y mayúsculas?

Comment: si me parece mas exacto

Comment: Por cierto con la nueva actualizacion de tu pregunta, el error es debido a que estas llamando a `contarCaracteres` en vez de `contarCaracteresV1 o contarCaracteresV2`, segun el codigo que has actualizado.

Comment: gracias @Eugeni Bejan pero en mi editor lo tenia bien ahora lo corregi aqui fijate de nuevo si puedes

Comment: `.map()` es una funcion para los arrays, abajo al hacer `str = str.split('')` estas transformando el String a un array, pero en el de arriba lo estas intentando hacer con el String directamente. [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)

Comment: gracias @x3k_js que tonteria de mi parte edite y olvide esa parte

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Contar números y letras de una cadena con javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291445/contar-n%c3%bameros-y-letras-de-una-cadena-con-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera.

1. Quitar los espacios en blanco y pasar el string a minúsculas(si es necesario)
2. Recorrer la cadena de texto en vez de pasarlo a un array.
3. Finalmente guardar el resultado en un object, donde la letra es la key y su total.

```js
function contarCaracteres(str) {
  //Pasamos la cadena a minusculas(por si lo necesitas)
  //str = str.toLowerCase()
  //quitamos los espacios en blanco
  str = str.replace(/\s/g, "");
  final = {} //Donde guardamos los resultados
  for(let char in str){ //Cogemos el indice de cada caracter
 if(str[char] in final) { //Si ya existe, simplemente aumentamos el contador
  final[str[char]] = final[str[char]] + 1
 } else { // Si no existe, lo inicializamos a 1
  final[str[char]] = 1
    }
}
  //Mostar los resultados
  tmp = ``
  Object.keys(final).forEach(function(letra){
    tmp += `La cantidad de ${letra} es: ${final[letra]} \n`
  })
  return tmp
}
let para_contar = "HOLA hOLA" //Fijate en la h min.
console.log(contarCaracteres(para_contar))
```

Espero que te sirva como ayuda.

Comment: Gracias @Eugeni Bejan es una buena respuesta me sirve de ayuda :)

Answer (score 3):

Una solución que podías aplicar es la siguiente:

- Eliminamos los carateres invisibles (`eg: str.replace(/\s/g, '') ===> string`)
- Convertimos la cadena a un arreglo (`eg: [...string] ==> array`)
- Utilizamos `reduce` para recorrer el arreglo y pasamos como segundo parámetro un objeto el cual usaremos para guardar la cantidad de veces que aparece cada letra (`eg: obj[char] = obj[char] + 1 || 1`)

#### Ejemplo

```js
function contarCaracteres(str) {
  return [...str.replace(/\s/g, '')]
    .reduce((obj, char) => {
      obj[char] = obj[char] + 1 || 1;
      return obj;
    }, {});
}

console.log(contarCaracteres("Hola mundo"));
```

Comment: +1. Muy buena solución

Answer (score 2):

Aqui lo estoy regresando cada caracter contado en un objeto..

```js
function contarCaracteresV3(str) {
    let cantidadLetras = []
    let caracteres = str.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '').split('').filter((c,i,self) => (
        self.indexOf(c) === i
    ))
    
    for(var i=0; i<caracteres.length; i++){
        let arreglo=[]
        str.split('').map(n => {
            if(n.toLowerCase() === caracteres[i]){
                arreglo.push(n)
            }          
        })
        cantidadLetras.push({[caracteres[i]]: arreglo.length})
    }

    return cantidadLetras
}

console.log(contarCaracteresV3("Abcaaa cada"));
```

Comment: +1 por espíritu deportivo, aunque creo que te estas complicando usando muchas funciones.

Answer (score 2):

Se puede hacer acumulando la cantidad de apariciones de cada letra en un array donde el indice es el código *ascii* del mismo.

Para convertir una cadena a *ascii* se puede emplear `letra.charCodeAt()` y para obtener lo contrario `String.fromCharCode(codigo)`:

```js
function contarCaracteres(cadena) {

    var cont=[];                                  //inicializar el contador
    ncad=cadena.split('');                        //dividir la cadena en caracteres
    for (var i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {     //recorrer la cadena
      letra=ncad[i].charCodeAt();                 //pasar cada letra a código ascii
      //antes de sumarlo verificar si ya existe en cont, de no ser así inicializarlo
      cont[letra]==undefined ? cont[letra]=1 : cont[letra]++  
    };
    total={};                                     //para guardar el resultado
    for (var i in cont)                           //recorrer el contador
      total[String.fromCharCode(i)]=cont[i];      //pasar el caracter de ascii a string y pasarle la cantidad
    return total;
  }
  
  console.log(contarCaracteres('aaasddddQQW'));
```

Este método diferencia mayúsculas de minúsculas.

Espero haber ayudado a resolver el problema, saludos.

Comment: Gracias @the-breaker genial el codigo... nunca habia visto el `charCodeAt()` ni el `fromCharCode()` me cuesta un poco de entender

Comment: te fijastes que si hay espacios tmb los cuenta por eso me complique un poco en mi respuesta..

Comment: @IsraelGonzález Para quitar los espacios de tu array puedes usar `array.filter(c => c!=' ')`

Comment: pq lo annado y me da un error de `charCodeAt()` y el  undefined

Comment: es por que filtrando la cadena con espacios el tamaño es diferente al del original, debes cambiar `cadena.length` por `ncad.length`