# Tengo otra duda con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-objeto

Tengo que hacer un script que me diga cual es el carácter que mas se repite en una palabra y llevo ya 3 horas liado y no doy con la solución, ya es el único ejercicio que me falta y no se como hacerlo

```
 function ejercicio5(){
    var palabra=document.getElementById("box1").value;
    palabra=palara.toLowerCase();
    var vecesRepetido=0;
    var letraRepetida='';
    for(var i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++)
    {
        var re = new RegExp("[^"+ palabra[i] +"]","g");
        var repetido=palabra.replace(re, "");

        if(repetido.length >= vecesRepetido)
        {
            vecesRepetido=repetido.length;
            letraRepetida=repetido[0];
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("variable").innerHTML=letraRepetida;
}
```

Comment: Hola, te puede ser de ayuda revisar esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/293564/77879

Comment: si acabo de solucionarlo era una tonteria me faltaban unas comillas XP

Comment: Si ya esta resuelto puedes cerrar la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el concepto de diccionario, u objeto, aquí tienes un código de ejemplo que te permite analizar cualquier caracter.

A medida que recorres un string vas registrando la existencia de dicho string en un diccionario, al registrarla inicializas la cantidad de coincidencias de dicho caracter en 1, si encuentras más coincidencias del caracter vas aumentando de una unidad dicha cuenta.

Finalmente recorres los elementos del diccionario y vas registrando qué caracter tuvo la mayor cantidad de coincidencias, una vez recorrido todo el diccionario muestras el primer caracter que tuvo la mayor cantidad de coincidencias. La función que te propongo acá retorna el caracter con su cantidad de ocurrencias.

```js
let example1 = "sad;asdoi13i214asasd";
let example2 = "aaabbc";

function mostRepeatedCharacter(data) {
  let dictionary = {};
  let mostCommon = '';
  let maxCount = 0;
  
  for (const character of data) {
    if (dictionary[character] !== undefined) {
      dictionary[character] += 1;
    } else {
      dictionary[character] = 1;
    }
  }
  
  for (const character in dictionary) {
    if (maxCount < dictionary[character]) {
      maxCount = dictionary[character];
      mostCommon = character;
    }
  }

  return [mostCommon, maxCount];
}

console.log(mostRepeatedCharacter(example1));
console.log(mostRepeatedCharacter(example2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un codigo para la busqueda de letras para un parrafo en Javascript.

Comparalo con el que has realizado:

```html
    <textarea id='box1' cols="40"  rows="5">Este es un texto de prueba para saber cual 
        es la letra que se repite mas en todo el parrafo</textarea>
    <p id='variable'></p>

    <script>   
            // listado de letras
            var stringBase = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','_'];
            // carga contenido 
            var palabra=document.getElementById("box1").value;
            var palabra = palabra.toLowerCase(); // pasar a minuscula
            var cantRepetida = 0;
            var letraRepetida ='';

            for (let index = 0; index <  stringBase.length; index++) {
                    // Agregar una variable a la expresion regular
                    var letra = new RegExp(stringBase[index],'g');
                    commparacion = (palabra.match(letra) || []).length;
                    console.log(letra); // letra
                    console.log(commparacion); // valor comparacion
                    // buscar cual es el que mas se repite
                    if (index==0) {
                        cantRepetida = commparacion;
                        letraRepetida = stringBase[index];
                        } else {
                            // asigna una nueva letra repetida si la nueva es mayor
                            if (commparacion>cantRepetida) {
                                cantRepetida = commparacion;
                                letraRepetida = stringBase[index];
                            }
                         
                        } // fin if
            } // fin for

            // salida
            document.getElementById("variable").innerHTML=letraRepetida + ' ' + cantRepetida;
            
    </script>
</body>
```

Es otra forma de resolver el problema, espero que pueda ayudarte.