# Detectar elementos repetidos y "sumarlos"

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una lista de elementos:

```
<div id="zapateria">
<div class="botas" cantidad="2"></div>
<div class="deportivas" cantidad="2"></div>
<div class="casuales" cantidad="2"></div>
<div class="casuales" cantidad="2"></div>
<div class="botas" cantidad="5"></div>
</div>
```

Necesito con jquery comprobar los elementos que son iguales y "sumar" las cantidad, es decir:

```
<div id="zapateria">
<div class="deportivas" cantidad="2"></div>
<div class="casuales" cantidad="4"></div>
<div class="botas" cantidad="7"></div>
</div>
```

He tenido éxito comprobando los elementos iguales, pero no sumando las cantidades. ¿Alguna ayuda? Muchas gracias.

Añado el código que tenía hecho.

```
var ver = {}; 
$('#zapateria div').each(function() { 
  var clas = $(this).attr("class");
  var can = $(this).attr("cantidad");
  if (ver[clas]) {
    var dupli = $(this).attr("cantidad")
    console.log(dupli);
  } else {
    ver[clas] = true;
  } 
})
```

Comment: Podrías poner el código que ya tienes?

Comment: puedes compartir el js que has escrito hasta ahora?

Comment: Disculpen, ya lo he editado!

Comment: [mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291445/contar-n%c3%bameros-y-letras-de-una-cadena-con-javascript) probablemente te ayude a resolver el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que te pueda ser util, un poco rustico pero la idea es esa.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="zapateria">
        <div class="botas" cantidad="2"></div>
        <div class="deportivas" cantidad="2"></div>
        <div class="casuales" cantidad="2"></div>
        <div class="casuales" cantidad="2"></div>
        <div class="botas" cantidad="5"></div>
    </div>
        <button type="button" id="btn_check"> Revisa</button>

        <script>
            $("#btn_check").click(function () {
                // array de recoleccion de valores
                var params_values = new Array();
                // array de resultados
                var resultado = new Array();
                $("#zapateria div").each(function () {
                    var classe = $(this).attr("class");
                    if(classe!=""){
                        var valor = $(this).attr("cantidad");
                        //alert(classe+":"+valor);
                        params_values.push({[classe]:valor});
                    }
                });

                //Suma valores
                $.each(params_values,function(item,value){
                    $.each(value,function(key,value){
                        var itemadded= objectFindByKey(resultado,key);
                        if(itemadded==null){
                            resultado.push({[key]:value});
                        }else{
                            var actualvalue = parseInt(itemadded[key]);
                            itemadded[key] =parseInt(itemadded[key])+parseInt(value);
                        }
                    });
                });

                //despliega valores
                $.each(resultado,function(index,object){
                    $.each(object,function(key,value){
                        alert(key + ":" + value );
                    });
                });

            });

            //busca objeto en array
            function objectFindByKey(array, key) {
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    var key_inarray = Object.keys(array[i]);
                    if (key_inarray == key) { 
                        return array[i];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución que yo haria es la siguiente.

1. Obtener los hijos del div con el id `zapateria`
2. Usar un objeto para guardar los valores teniendo en cuenta si ya existe ese grupo o no mediante el atributo `class`

Ejemplo:

```js
//Todos las opciones del div zapateria
const options = $('#zapateria').children()

//Donde guardaremos los resultados
let totalByClassName = {}

for (let op of options) {
    if (totalByClassName.hasOwnProperty(op.className)) {
        //Si la clave existe sumamos la cantidad
        totalByClassName[op.className] += Number(op.getAttribute('cantidad'))
    } else {
        //Si no existe simplemente lo inicializamos con la cantidad.
        totalByClassName[op.className] = Number(op.getAttribute('cantidad'))
    }
}

console.log(totalByClassName)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <div id="zapateria">
        <div class="botas" cantidad="2"></div>
        <div class="deportivas" cantidad="2"></div>
        <div class="casuales" cantidad="2"></div>
        <div class="casuales" cantidad="2"></div>
        <div class="botas" cantidad="5"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```