# Función para devolver cantidad de caracteres repetidos o ninguno

Tags: javascript

Hola estuve tiempo intentando programar una función que ingresando un *string* **s** te devuelva cierta cantidad de caracteres repetidos (o directamente ninguno) en función de **r** (ver código adjunto para entender la estructura de la función).

> si ingresamos => funcion ('hhooh',1) nos debe devolver=> 'hoh'
> si ingresamos => funcion ('hhooh',3) nos debe devolver=> 'hhooh'
> si ingresamos => funcion ('hhooh44t44',3) nos debe devolver=> 'hhooh44t44'

Nótese que no es solo de resolver con un filter, unique, etc. Porque el carácter se puede volver a repetir en otra instancia, en este caso el h se repite en 2 instancias, la primera va del index 0-1 y el otro index 4.

Acá esta lo que intente:

```js
function remover(s, r) {
  if (typeof s=== "string") {
    let caracteres = s.split("");
    let resultado = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < caracteres.length; ++i) {
      if (caracteres[i] === caracteres[i + 1]) {
        for (let j = 0; j < r; ++j) {
          console.log("won");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

remover("aa",4);
```

Comment: El planteamiento necesita mas detalles, en el ejemplo 1 `h` y `o` se repiten, `h` tres veces y `o` dos veces, luego en `funcion ('hhooh',1)`, ese `1` ¿Qué se supone que indica?  y después devuelven `hoh`, ¿Por qué? Hay que elaborar esos detalles en la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Contar números y letras de una cadena con javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291445/contar-n%c3%bameros-y-letras-de-una-cadena-con-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según entiendo tu problema, lo que necesitas es una función que reciba dos parámetros, **s** y **r**, donde **s** es un string que puede contener cualquier cantidad de caracteres repetidos. Y **r** representa la cantidad de repeticiones de un mismo carácter que pueden haber continuos.

```js
/**
 ** s string entrada
 ** r cantidad máxima de un mismo carácter que puede haber continuo en la respuesta
 ** Se espera que r >= 0
 **/
function repetidos(s, r) {
  let resultado = ''; // string donde se guardará el resultado
  
  // Si no puede haber repeticiones o el string está vacío, la respuesta es un string vacío
  if (r === 0 || s.length === 0) {
    return resultado;
  }
  
  // El primer carácter siempre hará parte de la respuesta
  resultado += s[0];
  
  // Cantidad de repeticiones que hemos visto en el último grupo de caracteres iguales
  // Por defecto, siempre habrá un carácter que hayamos visto (carácter i)
  var repeticiones = 1;
  
  for (var i = 1; i < s.length; ++i) {
    // Si este carácter es igual al anterior, hay una repetición más
    if (s[i] === s[i-1]) {
      ++repeticiones;
    } else {
      repeticiones = 1;
    }
    
    // Si hay menos o igual a r repeticiones continuas de este carácter, procedemos a incluirlo en la respuesta
    if (repeticiones <= r) {
      resultado += s[i];
    }
  }
  
  return resultado;
}

console.log(repetidos("aass", 1));
console.log(repetidos("aassa", 1));
console.log(repetidos("aaabbbcccaaabbbc", 2));
```

La idea es mantener una variable que indique la cantidad de repeticiones del carácter **i** que hemos visto contiguos. Si en un momento esta es mayor que **r**, simplemente no lo insertamos en el string de la respuesta.

Comment: No se como agradecerte además de darte la mejor respuesta, excelente tu trabajo