# Contador de palabras en un texto Javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy aprendiendo a programar en Javascript. Encontre un problema que basicamente tengo que leer un texto y encontrar la cantidad de palabras que se repiten.
la idea es obtener una lista de las palabras de la variable "text" y la cantidad de cada una de ellas

Este es mi codigo y no logro encontrar el inconveniente de que esta mal

```js
let text = "hola que tal, tal que mi nombre es Jhon Doe, estoy aqui, aqui estoy en una charla informativa"

function normalize(word){
    return word.toLowerCase().replace(/[.!,]/g , "")
    // con regex reemplazo (. ! y , ) de las palabras
}

function wordRepetitions(text){
    let dict = {};
    let separatedWords = text.split(" ");
    for (let word of separatedWords) {
        if (normalize(word) in dict) {
            ++dict[normalize(word)];
        } else {
            dict[normalize(word)] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Es una buena primera pregunta pero ¿podrías indicar qué es lo que está mal? ¿qué resultado esperas y qué resultado (o mensaje de error) obtienes? Puedes poner la información editando la pregunta.

Comment: no comprendo exactamente tu pregunta, pero [creo que esto te servira](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291445/contar-n%c3%bameros-y-letras-de-una-cadena-con-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código está bien pero incompleto. Quiero hacer énfasis en lo siguiente:

1. Que declares funciones no hace que se ejecuten.
2. Tú decides que debe retornar una función: no es automático.
3. `function wordRepetitions(text)` no significa que reciba tu variable `text`, solo recibe un argumento que en el entorno de ejecución se llamará `text`.

Teniendo esto en cuenta, realiza los siguientes cambios:

```javascript
const variableText = "hola que tal, tal que mi nombre es Jhon Doe, estoy aqui, aqui estoy en una charla informativa"

// función flecha, esta si devuelve automático cuando no se usa llaves
// como ves, estoy generando otra variable de scope, "arg" y funciona igual
const normalize = (arg) => arg.toLowerCase().replace(/[.!,]/g , "");

function wordRepetitions(text){
    let dict = {};
    let separatedWords = text.split(" ");
    for (let word of separatedWords) {
        if (normalize(word) in dict) {
            ++dict[normalize(word)];
        } else {
            dict[normalize(word)] = 1;
        }
    }
    return dict; // aquí devuelves el resultado de la operación
}

// como ves, estoy enviando `variableText` como argumento, que en el entorno
// de la función "wordRepetitions", pasará a llamarse "text"
const resultado = wordRepetitions(variableText);

// se imprime en consola el objeto
console.log(resultado);
```

Por supuesto existen muchas maneras de escribir tu código, unas mejores que otras, pero me limito a responder tu pregunta y decirte por qué no funciona: porque está incompleto y no gatillas/devuelves/gestionas ningún resultado/función.

Espero te sea de ayuda, nos comentas.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta para hacer insistir en lo que te señalo, si ya la leíste, vuelve a verla por favor. Ojalá esté claro, nos comentas.

Comment: Mas que claro, muchisimas gracias por el tiempo

Comment: Si responde a tu solicitud, por favor, cierra la pregunta. Gracias!

Comment: @Devandmus, por las dudas: no hay un cierre de pregunta. Imagino que estas hablando en todo caso de "aceptar la respuesta".

Answer (score 0):

Esta solución podría servirte.

- `text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "").split(" ").map( w => w.toLowerCase())` limpias todo lo que no sea
  una letra, número o espaciol, separas las palabras por espacios y obtienes un array sobre el cual trabajar con todas las palabras normalizadas en minusculas
- `words.forEach` iteras sobre cada palabra del array
- `words.filter(t => t === word)` Filtras el arreglo de palabras por cada iteracion
- `arrayFilter.length > 1` Si es mayor a uno entonces la palabra está repetida
- `repetidos.filter(r => r.word === word).length === 0` Para evitar que no se agregue dos veces el mismo objeto ya encontrado al array de duplicados.

Saludos

```js
const text = 'hola que tal, tal que mi nombre es Jhon Doe, estoy aqui, aqui estoy en una charla informativa'
const words = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "").split(" ").map( w => w.toLowerCase())
let repetidos = []
words.forEach(word => {
  const arrayFilter = words.filter(t => t === word)
  if (arrayFilter.length > 1) {
    if (repetidos.filter(r => r.word === word).length === 0) repetidos.push({
      word,
      total: arrayFilter.length
    })
  }
})
console.log(repetidos)
```